# How to connect to a postgres database when having two docker-compose files?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

First I have built an image using Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*-SNAPSHOT.jar
ADD ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

as I have two docker-compose files one for production:

```
version: "3"

services:
    app:
      image: "demo:latest"
      container_name: demo-production-api
      restart: always
      depends_on:
        - "productiondb"
      environment:
        - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://productiondb:5432/testdb
        - SPRING_DATASOURCE_HIKARI_JDBC_URL=jdbc:postgresql://productiondb:5432/testdb
        - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USER=tester
        - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=test
        - SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL_AUTO=update
      ports:
        - "8440:8443"

    productiondb:
      image: "postgres:latest"
      container_name: productiondb
      ports:
        - "5430:5432"
      environment:
        - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      volumes:
        - postgres-db-production:/usr/local/var/postgres


volumes:
  postgres-db-production:
```

and one for develop:

```
version: "3"

services:
  app:
    image: "demo:latest"
    container_name: demo-develop-api
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - "developdb"
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://developdb:5432/testdb
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_HIKARI_JDBC_URL=jdbc:postgresql://developdb:5432/testdb
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USER=tester
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=test
      - SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL_AUTO=update
    ports:
      - "8441:8443"

  developdb:
    image: "postgres:latest"
    container_name: developdb
    ports:
      - "5431:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    volumes:
    - postgres-db-develop:/usr/local/var/postgres


volumes:
  postgres-db-develop:
```

I build both images using:

```
docker-compose -p demo-production-api -f docker-compose.yml up -d && docker-compose -p demo-develop-api -f docker-compose-develop.yml up -d
```

Now I was able to build both environments demo-develop-api and demo-production-api as well, the Spring Boot application from demo-develop-api docker image runs using the command:

```
docker run -it demo-develop-api
```

The application runs but I keep getting this error:

> Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: productiondb

The above error happened after changing the database host in the **application.properties** file from **localhost** to **productiondb** first I was getting the following:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432
> refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the
> postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.

Why this issue occurring or what is the cause?
How to solve this kind of issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a long time of debugging and trials, hopefully, this is is going to save people hours, it turned out that actually, the Spring Boot application inside the container was restarting runs and crashes without any errors, which made me more confused why it is not listening or opening a port. I even doubt it that it could be a firewall or something. So basically I just tried to get a shell from the container by doing:

`docker exec -it <container id or image> sh`

Note: Since I am using the image `openjdk:8-jdk-alpine` don't do below you will not get a shell:

`docker exec -it <container id or image> bash`

Then I tried to get a list of open ports by doing:

`netstat -tulpn | grep ":8443"`

The port `8443` was not listed, I thought it could be a problem with the java program not being running, tried to execute the spring boot which executed but without any errors and the shell itself was exiting which made me more confused.
Until I have found out that container was restartig because of Spring Boot was crashing. So I enabled verbose mode by adding the below properties to `application.properties` then rebuild the image again:

`logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG`

`logging.level.org.hibernate=DEBUG`

So I retried the last above steps where I get a shell and execute the `app.jar` and it turned out that the database `testdb` did not exist.

UPDATE: So to sum up here how I modifed my project, I created two Spring Boot Profiles for my case one for develop `application-develop.properties` and one for production `application-production.properties`:

So inside the `application-develop.properties` I have it mapped to a develop postgres container host and port:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://developdb:5432/testdb
spring.datasource.hikari.jdbc-url=jdbc:postgresql://developdb:5432/testdb
spring.datasource.username=tester
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.datasource.password=test
spring.jpa.database-platform=postgres
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
server.port=8443
```

And for `application-production.properties`:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://productiondb:5432/testdb
spring.datasource.hikari.jdbc-url=jdbc:postgresql://productiondb:5432/testdb
spring.datasource.username=tester
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.datasource.password=test
spring.jpa.database-platform=postgres
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
server.port=8443
```

And in the docker-compose file for develop I just define the Spring Boot profile environment variable to:

```
environment:
  - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=develop
```

And for production docker-compose file I define it as below:

```
environment:
  - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=production
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see it, the issue might be that you have binded port 5430 and 5431 to 5432 and you might be having the port set to 5432 in your application.resources file. Your application should be trying to connect to the database by using either port 5430 or 5431 for production and development respectively. Please check and try this. So, make a port change in the application.resources file.

Comment: `5430` and `5431` are internal ports of the container already mapped to `5432` they have to be different so I can get two separate database containers. as for port specified in application.properties file in resources it has to be external port which is already mapped `5430:5432`, `5431:5432` in docker-compose files.

Comment: I did netstat from both postgres databases containers shell and I can see only port 5432 is on LISTEN mode.

Comment: 5430 and 5431 aren't internal ports of the container, they are the ports on which the internal port of the container ( in our case 5432) should be exposed on the host system. They are basically getting binded. But I realised that you haven't created a database by the name testdb.(you can see that you haven't defined an environmental variable POSTGRES_DB=testdb , by using this variable a default db with the above mentioned name will be created during startup). Because of which you are getting UnknownHostException). So add this environment variable to docker-compose and try.

Comment: Yes that was it, thank you sir. I found out that after me noticing that the container is restarting with help from a person I met in IRC chat because Spring Boot application was crashing because of testdb not being created at first. The only thing I am trying to figure out is how to access the container through 127.0.0.1:8441 as I can see now port 8443 is listening inside the container which is mapped to 0.0.0.0:8441 host port but I am not able to access it from host through 127.0.0.1:8441 only by http://192.168.99.100:8014/.

Comment: As I am planning to make this accessible from outside by a domain name for e.g. coolsite.com:8441/api/v1/login

Comment: I even set the spring property variable in the `application.properties` file `server.address=0.0.0.0` (Any IPv4). But it is weird I am not able to access it.

Comment: Glad that you have resolved this. Did you resolve the access to the server through host machine as you were saying that you weren't able to access using 127.0.0.1:8441?

Comment: if you want to have your site accessible through coolsite.com:8441, make sure first its being accessible through either localhost:8441 or 127.0.0.1:8441(I guess you will be able to figure out how you can resolve this issue if it still persists) then later you can simple go to your /etc/hosts file on your host machine and add a line over there 127.0.0.1 coolsite.com